# rqt won't launch: KeyError: 'label'

Tags: ros-melodic, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am getting a trace error when I try to launch rqt.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/ros/melodic/bin/rqt", line 13, in <module>
        sys.exit(main.main())
      File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_gui/main.py", line 59, in main
        return super(Main, self).main(argv, standalone=standalone, plugin_argument_provider=plugin_argument_provider, plugin_manager_settings_prefix=str(hash(os.environ['ROS_PACKAGE_PATH'])))
      File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/main.py", line 596, in main
        plugin_manager.discover()
      File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_manager.py", line 125, in discover
        self._plugin_menu.add_plugin(plugin_descriptor)
      File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_menu.py", line 81, in add_plugin
        action = QAction(action_attributes['label'], menu_manager.menu)
    KeyError: 'label'
```

However, rqt launches correctly when I launch my plugin in standalone, e.g.:

```
rqt --standalone rqt_mypkg
```

The standard plugins such as rqt_graph and rqt_bag also work correctly.

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340631/rqt-won%27t-launch:-keyerror:-%27label%27/) by [gallantandre](https://answers.ros.org/users/50474/gallantandre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-12-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gallantandre](https://answers.ros.org/users/50474/gallantandre/) on 2020-01-15**:
Thank you for the comment. But the problem is not with my plugin, it is when I try to launch rqt via `rqt` command. It seems to have difficulty loading the menu bar.

When I launch my plugin or any other common plugins, there is no problem.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-01-15**:
The second sentence of my previous comment still applies. You can also try `rqt --clear-config`.

**Comment by [gallantandre](https://answers.ros.org/users/50474/gallantandre/) on 2020-01-15**:
Hmm, I seem to be missing something. I am not trying to launch a plugin, so would there be a plugin.xml file? Is there a master plugin.xml file somewhere in the installation folder?

Also `rqt --clear-config` throws the exact same Traceback.

**Comment by [gallantandre](https://answers.ros.org/users/50474/gallantandre/) on 2020-01-15**:
OH! My bad, it *was* my plugin that was causing the problem! There was no label field and the rqt_gui could not add my plugin to the list in the menu!

Thank you so much!

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-01-15**:
I converted my first comment into an answer. Please consider checking the mail on the left of it to mark it as the right answer if it works for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might be missing the `label` tag in your plugin xml file? If you could point to your code or update the question with some of the content of your package (maybe the `plugin.xml` file will do it) we could give you more precise feedback.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gallantandre](https://answers.ros.org/users/50474/gallantandre/) on 2020-01-15**:
Indeed, when the main rqt interface tries to load its menu, it looks for all plugins. For each plugin, it needs a label tag in the `plugin.xml` file.

The fact that my plugin worked in standalone mode caused my brain to turn into mush apparently.

Thanks